# Resolution of $2\mathbf{\hat{i}}+3\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ along $\mathbf{\hat{i}}+\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{i}}-\mathbf{\hat{j}}$

Tags: vectors

I was solving this problem:

> Resolve $2\mathbf{\hat{i}}+3\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ along $\mathbf{\hat{i}}+\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{i}}-\mathbf{\hat{j}}$.

I proceeded as below:

Let $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be the given vectors in the same order. Let
$$\mathbf{A}=\lambda\mathbf{a}+\mu\mathbf{b}$$
Putting the values and rearranging,
$$2\mathbf{\hat{i}}+3\mathbf{\hat{j}}= (\lambda+\mu)\mathbf{\hat{i}}+(\lambda-\mu)\mathbf{\hat{j}}$$
Then, noting that two vectors are equal iff their magnitudes as well as directions are equal, first we equate the directions and taking $\tan$ of both sides.
$$\frac 3 2 = \frac{\lambda-\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$$
Thus, $\lambda = -5\mu$.

Now, taking magnitudes and squaring,
$$13 = 2(\lambda^2+\mu^2)$$
Using our previous equation and doing some work, we get
$$\lambda=\pm \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}\textrm{ and } \mu = \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
However, I find no way of choosing which sign.

The book says the answer is $\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

I know there is the way to take components by using dot product. But since the book has not introduced it yet, I wonder if there's a way I showed above.

Edit: As Jeea pointed out, the correct answers are
$$\lambda=\pm \frac{5}{2}\textrm{ and } \mu = \mp \frac{1}{2}$$
However, this worsens the situation, this time even the answers are different, let alone sign.

Comment: Firstly $\lambda = -5 \mu$ so they are of opposite sign. Secondly $\lambda + \mu$ and $\lambda - \mu$ are both positive. This gives the required answer

Comment: I guess substituting will lead to $\mu^2 = 1/4$

Comment: I think you should consider thinking it through a pictorial or a graphical diagram of what you're solving. that is surely gonna help you out in these type of questions where sign related queries occur. Just tell me if its not enough and I'll provide an answer.

Comment: That seems good, @jeea! However, considering your second comment, the situation gots worsened. May you or Prajwal tell where's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $13=2(26\mu^2)$, I think you miscounted the powers of $2$. (The book probably instead worked with the unit vectors $(\mathbf{\hat{i}}\pm\mathbf{\hat{j}})/\sqrt{2}$.) The easiest simultaneous solution of $\lambda+\mu=2,\,\lambda-\mu=3$ averages the equations to get $\lambda=\tfrac52$, so $\mu=2-\lambda=-\tfrac12$.

Comment: I got that easily. If we go with the book, then we get $2\mathbf{\hat{i}}+3\mathbf{\hat{j}}=2\sqrt{2}\mathbf{\hat{i}}+3\sqrt{2}\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ which makes no sense. Or maybe I did it the incorrect way; components don't work this way.

Comment: Or just thought that they could work this way: Instead of writing $\mathbf{A}=\lambda\mathbf{a}+\mu\mathbf{b}$, we should write $\mathbf{A}=\lambda\mathbf{\hat{a}}+\mu\mathbf{\hat{b}}$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Hence my sentence in brackets.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked with the book which says, "...along the directions of ..."!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is using matrix techniques:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} + \mu \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}
\\ = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda\\\mu\end{bmatrix}$$

So take inverse and premultiply and we get $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda\\\mu\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}5/2\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I think if he's not yet introduced to scalar product by the book then this might be too much for an answer.

Comment: I know all these concepts, but I wish to go par with the book.

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding unit vectors: $1/√2 (i+j),$ and $1/√2(i-j)$;

$2i+3j=$

$a(1/√2)(i+j)+b(1/√2)(i-j);$

$a+b=2√2; a-b=3√2;$

$a=(5√2)/2=5/√2;$

$b=√2/2=-1/√2.$

Comment: Why are we supposed to consider the unit vectors?

Comment: ultralrgend5385. You have a point. The question seems ambivalent: 'Resolution' along 2 (independent) vectors. If it were 'projection along' we would rather think of projection onto unit vectors, this is what I would understand. The result given seems in favour of the latter.

Comment: Okay, let me conform from the book once again.